# How to update table value based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, tabs, foreign-keys

I have a table called `Product` and its data and table structure something like as follows,

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| ProductId | ProductName | SortValue |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1157      | ABC         | 7         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1156      | DEF         | 3         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1155      | GHI         | 4         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1154      | JKL         | 2         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1153      | MNO         | 1         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1152      | PQR         | 5         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1151      | STU         | 6         |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I have another table called `LocationProdut` which is the reference product table and location table, for each location `productid` has its own sort value.sample data and table structure its as follows,

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| fkLocationId | fkProductId | Sortvalue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1157        | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1156        | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1155        | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1154        | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1153        | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1152        | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19           | 1151        | 7         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20           | 1155        | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20           | 1154        | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20           | 1153        | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20           | 1152        | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20           | 1151        | 7         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21           | 1155        | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21           | 1154        | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21           | 1153        | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21           | 1152        | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21           | 1151        | 7         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now I need to update `SortValue` coulmn in `LocationProdut` table, in order to `Product` table's `SortValue` for only `fkLocationId = 19 & 20`

**Expected output as follows.**

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| fkBranchId | fkServiceId | Sortvalue |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1157        | 7         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1156        | 3         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1155        | 4         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1154        | 2         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1153        | 1         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1152        | 5         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 19         | 1151        | 6         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20         | 1155        | 4         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20         | 1154        | 2         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20         | 1153        | 1         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20         | 1152        | 5         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 20         | 1151        | 6         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21         | 1155        | 3         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21         | 1154        | 4         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21         | 1153        | 5         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21         | 1152        | 6         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 21         | 1151        | 7         |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `inner join` to update the required rows:

```
UPDATE LP
  SET 
      LP.Sortvalue = P.SortValue
FROM LocationProduct LP
JOIN Product P ON LP.fkProductId = P.ProductId
WHERE fkLocationId IN(19, 20);
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e99b62388ed5aea900e806ddc647a38)**.

Comment: suppose I have more than 100 locations id, so have any other way to do it without using `IN(19, 20);` , I need a most efficient way to do this, thanks anyway your answer

Comment: @Adam you can put those ids into another table and join that too while updating the records.

Comment: sir, can you provide me sample code, How can I do it like that, I mean as you suggested, how can use another table

Comment: @Adam Please find the example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07c69866aaf28dd783440744b2365236).

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE        targetTable
SET           targetTable.targetColumn = s.sourceColumn
FROM          targetTable t
INNER JOIN    sourceTable s
ON            t.matchingColumn = s.matchingColumn
```

Comment: This is not my expected answer, please provide me complete one.